# MVC 4.0 Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building out a custom section in my site, and it has multiple routes, so I have my controller set up as follows:

- Controller - ExportToExcel Action
- EomSpreasheet Parameters
- eomdate, siteid

In the routeconfig I have the following set up.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "EomCoverSheet",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{eomdate}/{siteid}",
defaults:
new
{
    controller = "ExcelExport",
    action = "EomSpreasheet",
    eomdate = UrlParameter.Optional,
    siteid= UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

When I make the call to the controller, and in the code as I am stepping through it, the values for eomdate and siteid are null. When I look at the routedata I can see the action and controller, but the parameters are for another route that I have in the routeconfig file.

I have done this numerous times in the past, but this is the first time I have seen this behavior and not sure how to resolve it. Any help ye can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Whic is the order of your route registrations?

Comment: Show the signature of the method and how you are calling the method. Note also, only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional` (it will work, but if you only provide one parameter, you url will be `...?eomdate=xxx&siteid=yyy` rather than `.../xxx/yyy`)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note about .NET routing are:

1. The routes are executed in order from the first registered to the last, and the first match wins.
2. Route tokens (such as `{controller}`) match a URL segment with anything unless you put a constraint on them.

This means that the route you posted will match *any* URL with 2, 3, or 4 segments in it. This is not very useful if you have a default route that already matches *any* URL with 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments because you will have a large amount of overlap and depending on the order they are declared, one of them will always override the other.

One practical solution to this is to use a literal value for a route segment, and to place this route before your more generic routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "EomCoverSheet",
url: "ExcelExport/{action}/{eomdate}/{siteid}",
defaults:
new
{
    controller = "ExcelExport",
    action = "EomSpreasheet",
    eomdate = UrlParameter.Optional,
    siteid= UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

What this does is make this route only match the URL if it begins with an `ExcelExport` segment and has 0, 1, 2, or 3 more segments with anything in them.

```
/ExcelExport/
/ExcelExport/EomSpreadsheet/
/ExcelExport/EomSpreadsheet/2015-01-01/
/ExcelExport/EomSpreadsheet/2015-01-01/123
```

If you want this to only match the URL if it contains all 4 segments, you can make the segments required instead of optional.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "EomCoverSheet",
url: "ExcelExport/{action}/{eomdate}/{siteid}",
defaults:
new
{
    controller = "ExcelExport"
});
```

Now the route will only match a 4 segment URL that begins with `ExcelExport`.

```
/ExcelExport/EomSpreadsheet/2015-01-01/123
```

Two other possible solutions to this problem are:

1. Use [areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
2. Use [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).